# splitting lines with " from an infile in python

Tags: python, split

I have a series of input files such as:

```
chr1    hg19_refFlat    exon    44160380    44160565    0.000000    +   .   gene_id "KDM4A"; transcript_id "KDM4A";
chr1    hg19_refFlat    exon    19563636    19563732    0.000000    -   .   gene_id "EMC1"; transcript_id "EMC1";
chr1    hg19_refFlat    exon    52870219    52870551    0.000000    +   .   gene_id "PRPF38A"; transcript_id "PRPF38A";
chr1    hg19_refFlat    exon    53373540    53373626    0.000000    -   .   gene_id "ECHDC2"; transcript_id "ECHDC2_dup2";
chr1    hg19_refFlat    exon    11839859    11840067    0.000000    +   .   gene_id "C1orf167"; transcript_id "C1orf167";
chr1    hg19_refFlat    exon    29037032    29037154    0.000000    +   .   gene_id "GMEB1"; transcript_id "GMEB1";
chr1    hg19_refFlat    exon    103356007   103356060   0.000000    -   .   gene_id "COL11A1"; transcript_id "COL11A1";
```

in my code I am trying to capture 2 elements from each line, the first is the number after where it says exon, the second is the gene (the number and letter combo surrounded by "", e.g. "KDM4A". Here is my code:

```
    with open(infile,'r') as r:
        start = set([line.strip().split()[3] for line in r])
        genes = set([line.split('"')[1] for line in r])
        print len(start)
        print len(genes)
```

for some reason start works fine but genes is not capturing anything. Here is the output:

```
 48050
 0
```

I figure this is something to do with the "" surrounding the gene name but if I enter this on the terminal it works fine:

```
>>> x = 'A b P "G" m'
>>> x
'A b P "G" m'
>>> x.split('"')[1]
'G'
>>>
```

Any solutions would be much appreciated? If even if its a completely different way of capturing the 2 items of data from each line. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because your file object is exhausted when you loop over it once here `start = set([line.strip().split()[3] for line in r])` again you are trying to loop here `genes = set([line.split('"')[1] for line in r])` over the exhausted file object

**Solution:**

You could seek to the start of the file (this is one of the solutions)

**Modification to your code:**

```
with open(infile,'r') as r:
    start = set([line.strip().split()[3] for line in r])
    r.seek(0, 0)
    genes = set([line.split('"')[1] for line in r])
    print len(start)
    print len(genes)
```

Comment: Ok, so what should the OP do about it?

Comment: thanks, I've not come across the seek method before, very useful. I'm accepting this answer because its the shortest most concise and solves the problem with 1 short line of code

Comment: @user3062260 happy to help

Answer (score 4):

You may use regex.

```
with open(file) as f:
    start = []
    genes = []
    for line in f:
        st, gen = re.search(r'\bexon\s+(\d+)\b.*?\s+gene_id\s+"([^"]*)"', line).groups()
        start.append(st)
        genes.append(gen)
    print set(start)
    print set(genes)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gP1tP2/1)

Comment: Now you have two problems!

Comment: But won't `start` and `genes` now be strings instead of sets? Seems pretty different than what the OP had initially.

Answer (score 2):

You could load all the lines into a list, and then perform `split` on each item in that list (not sure how efficient that is if the file is long)

```
with open(infile) as r:
    lines = [line for line in r]
    start = set([line.strip().split()[3] for line in lines])
    genes = set([line.split('"')[1] for line in lines])
```

Comment: I had thought of this but the file is massive and I need to loop through 24 similar sized files so it would take ages.

Answer (score 2):

Using shlex (as it's like shell arguments), neutralizes multiple spaces and quotations
Not sure if it's faster, but safe and kind of nice

```
import shlex
with open(infile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = shlex.split(line.replace(';', ''))
        print parts[3], parts[9]
```

Comment: I haven't come across shlex before and it seems to work to solve the problem quite nicely. Resetting the loop seems the simplest solution though.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it was failing to load `genes` is that you would have needed to restart reading the file from the start. The following approach though should work:

```
import re

start = set()
genes = set()

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        s, g = re.match(r'(?:.*?\s+){3}(\d+).*"(\w+)"', line).groups()
        start.add(s)
        genes.add(g)

print start
print genes
```

Giving you the output:

```
set(['44160380', '29037032', '103356007', '19563636', '53373540', '52870219', '11839859'])
set(['COL11A1', 'PRPF38A', 'KDM4A', 'C1orf167', 'EMC1', 'GMEB1', 'ECHDC2_dup2'])
```